# Php, can not write to file

Tags: php, azure, fwrite, ubuntu-18.04, mounted-volumes

Each time I run it the file.txt is 0kb

- Permission for that file is 777 owner www-data:www-data
- The /var/www/html is on an external HD mounted to the server.
- Server is Ubuntu 18.04
- Azure hosted
- PHP 7.2.19
- Apache 2

I have this code

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $file = 'file.txt';
    $mf = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($mf, 'hi-----');
    fclose($mf);
    echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: What return fopen ? What return fwrite ?

Comment: Is file.txt created by fopen ?

Comment: @GabrieleMartini thank you for being the first to respond - turned out that the disk had no space :( 
thanks a mil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my disk ran out of space and the file was not being written